# How to know which data object are being used in which other object in R

Tags: r

I have a data.table and I want to know which all data objects are using any part of the data.table object in R. Is there any package function to know that.

Comment: Can you give a reproducible example? As is, the question is too broad to be answerable.

Comment: Is this the kind of output you want? `attr(dat_table, "names")`

Comment: I guess you are looking for what is called "data provenance" / "data lineage". I would suggest you take a look at the RDataTracker tool that is part of the End-to-end-provenance project here: https://github.com/End-to-end-provenance/End-to-end-provenance.github.io/blob/master/RTools.md